# How to show the function name with unresolved referenced symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker

[This question](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/v8-users/G_VoCqRBqt4/-TNx8lacBQAJ) shows that linker shows the error indicating the function with a referenced symbol:

> v8_libbase.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved
> external symbol __imp_timeGetTime 
> **referenced in function**
> "public: void
> __cdecl v8::base::Win32Time::SetToCurrentTime(void)" (?SetToCurrentTime@Win32Time@base@v8@@QEAAXXZ)
>
> v8_libbase.lib(time.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_timeGetTime

But the error in Visual Studio 2015 that I'm using the doesn't contain `referenced in function` part. Is there a way to configure a studio to show the `referenced in function` part?

Here is the list of errors I get:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: v8, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>  v8.cpp
1>v8_libbase.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_timeGetTime
1>v8_libbase.lib(time.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_timeGetTime
1>v8_libbase.lib(stack_trace_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_StackWalk64
1>v8_libbase.lib(stack_trace_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SymSetOptions
1>v8_libbase.lib(stack_trace_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SymFunctionTableAccess64
1>v8_libbase.lib(stack_trace_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SymGetModuleBase64
1>v8_libbase.lib(stack_trace_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SymGetLineFromAddr64
1>v8_libbase.lib(stack_trace_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SymInitialize
1>v8_libbase.lib(stack_trace_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SymGetSearchPathW
1>v8_libbase.lib(stack_trace_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SymSetSearchPathW
1>v8_libbase.lib(stack_trace_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SymFromAddr
1>v8_libbase.lib(stack_trace_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_PathRemoveFileSpecW
1>C:\Users\mkore\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\v8\x64\Release\v8.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 11 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message you are getting? It might be referring to a virtual function, which doesn't have to be referenced to be required.

Comment: You don't need the missing part to either diagnose or resolve this issue. Just link with the required library.

Comment: @yzt, I don't know what is the required library. That's the problem

Comment: Google for the function names. My point is that all the required info is already in the message.

Comment: @yzt, yeah, I get your point, thanks, ___imp_StackWalk64_ is the name of the function. Just wondering why it's not showing the entire part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the missing part to diagnose and fix these errors. These error's happen when you call a function (or reference a variable, but that's not as common) in your code that the linker can't find a definition for among all the object and library files it is linking together. For example, if your function `A` calls an external function `B`, and B is missing, then the linker issues this error saying "unresolved external symbol B".

In these cases, `A` (which is what you say is missing from your error report) is usually completely irrelevant (unless you want to figure out why the hell you are calling B in the first place.)

First of all, in majority of cases, these errors mean that you are missing a library (or source file) from your build.

If you have no idea at all what the missing libraries are, start googling the verbatim symbol name, e.g. `__imp_StackWalk64`, `__imp_SymSetOptions`, etc.

If you have a little more experience, you'll realize that these are all Win32 functions and their common names are `timeGetTime`, `StackWalk64`, etc.

Then it just becomes a matter of finding these names in MSDN and scrolling to the bottom of the page to see the corresponding libraries to these missing functions.

For example, I believe in this particular case, you are failing to link with `winmm.lib`, `dbghelp.lib`, and `shlwapi.lib` (at least.)

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else that's desperately been trying to embed V8 for several days, and in fact is desperate enough to scroll down past the first StackOverflow answer, the missing library is `dbghelp.lib`.

Keep pushing, brother. Salvation awaits those that reach the embedded V8 mountain top.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).